# ¿Como reducir consumo cpu freetype2?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

Estoy utilizando la librería freetype para dibujar texto en un jugo, pero con unas cuantas lineas de texto comienza aumentar el consumo del procesador llegando a un 100% bajando a 20 fps, limitado a 60 fps.

He estado probando con

https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html
https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step2.html

Utilizando `FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap` para guardar el mapa de bit de cada letra, logre que bajara a un 20% con la misma cantidad de texto, pero aun es mucho.

El texto que utilizo tiene solo 416 caracteres, esta pagina tiene mucho texto mas y consume menos del 1%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estaba utilizando `glTexImage2D` cada vez que mostraba una imagen (por cada fotograma), ahora solo lo ejecuto una vez y obtengo la textura con `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id_textura);` con esto, el consumo de procesador bajo al 4%, si multiplico por 10 la cantidad de texto (4160 caracteres) aumenta a un 18%

**VERSIÓN 2**

Siguiendo este tutorial he bajado un poco el consumo, pero no lo que esperaba.
https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Text-Rendering

Caracteres: 200, 1.000, 10.000, 13.800

FPS:        508, 180, 25, 20

**VERSIÓN 3:**

Utilizando un atlas de textura es mucho mas rápido, mas de 7 veces con mucho texto.
Siguiendo este tutorial https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Text_Rendering_02

Caracteres: 200, 1.000, 10.000, 13.800, 27.600

FPS:        940, 880, 216, 150, 75

**VERSIÓN 3.1**
Utilizando sdl2 y glew

Caracteres: 200, 1.000, 10.000, 13.800, 27.600, 30.000

FPS:        2000, 1500, 205, 155, 76, 70

Todo esto con un procesador **AMD ATHLON II x3** y una tarjeta de video **NVIDIA GT610**